# Is it better to buy the stock over a long call if volatility is high?

Tags: options, call-options

I've been looking at buying long calls of $ZM, but when calculating my P/L i'm thinking it's basically a wash to buy the option and might as well just buy the stock. Wondering if this is true or if there is an advantage in this case to buying calls.

Right now the stock is ~$105 and the `March 20 90 call` is ~$20.

My breakeven would be around $110 in this case.

Since implied volatility is so high right now (124) does that make buying this option not a great idea and I might as well buy the stock instead? Is there any leverage advantage to buying calls over the stock at this price?

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: The locals don't like options :->)

Comment: Says who? (Maybe DV was because this felt like 'opinion'?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any leverage advantage to buying calls over the stock at this price?

The call costs $20 and the stock costs $105.  That's about 5:1 leverage and that is the advantage.

> Since implied volatility is so high right now (124) does that make buying this option not a great idea and I might as well buy the stock instead?

You're paying up because IV is high.  $5 is a lot  of time premium for an 18 day option.  But there's good news, it's down to about $3.  And that is the disadvantage.  Theta decay is really going to speed up now and in order to offset it, you're going to have to be directionally right in a short period of time. If this other than an earnings play, only 18 days isn't a great plan.

Here's the kicker.  ZM announces earnings on Wednesday.  If ZM IV follows previous EAs then that 124 IV is going to contract to 50-60 and that means that 20-25% of your premium is going to disappear (loss) just because of the EA.  While I'm not going to suggest that it's a better strategy, if I was still playing EAs, I'd sell some expensive premium elsewhere to offset (a vertical?).    How smart that is would depend on what ZM does Wednesday.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It is an earnings play and i'm pretty new to options still.

Let's say ZM hovers around $105 and then shoots to $120 after earnings. Does that mean that IV will increase (or stay high like it is now)?

Comment: Also when you say `I'd sell some expensive premium elsewhere to offset (a vertical?)` can you suggest the name of what this options strategy would be called so that I can read about it to try to understand where you're coming from when you suggest this?

Comment: IV is going to contract after the EA no matter what happens to the price of ZM.  If ZM were to shoot to $120 after earnings, your $90 call would trade at close to intrinsic value ($30) and IV would not be a factor at all.  However in your original example where you pay $5 of time premium, it would have to reach approximately $110 to break even and then start to make money.

Comment: The option strategy is called a vertical spread.  It has very different R/R parameters than a long call.  You can Google for info but a better source would be reading "Options as a Strategic Investment" by Lawrence G. McMillan.  I'd also suggest that since you're pretty new to options that you avoid earnings plays.  Without a deep understanding of the effect of IV on premium and what strategies are more effective in this situation, you're blindly speculating on long shots at the track - high likelihood of losing with an occasional big payoff.